# How to override Gson default DateTypeAdapter?

Tags: java, gson, android

I created a custom Date deserializer:

```
private static class DateJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                return df.parse(json.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + json.getAsString()
                + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
    }
}
```

I added this to my gsonBuilder:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateJsonDeserializer());
```

But if I would like to parse a date I see the built in DateTypeAdapter class used, why? I would like to use my date deserializer.
I use retrofit 2.1.0, Gson 2.8.0, converter-gson 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that Date.class is the correct class? Maybe it uses a subclass of Date.class ?

Comment: I use java.util.Date class everywhere. I checked in retrofit the converterFactories and I see that the first is the BuiltInConverters, and it's contains a DateTypeAdapter which called first and its thrown an exception..